# Connecting and disconnecting internet in "IE data scraping" via "VBA"

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am scraping data from an active server page (ASP) that it change every second. I need load page,disconnect internet(making data static and untouched), scrape it, connect internet, and refresh the page and so on...
**Here is the main problem**:
When VBA click on the filter button and server refreshes data. I need all data(3 filters) altogether at the same time. Data is changing over the time(time frame data), with every click on my filters data has been refreshed by server. I need to stop data refreshment before changing the filters. Here is the sequence:
1-Page loading
2-Stop(or hold) data refreshment from server(e.g. disconnecting IE from internet)
3-Clicking on filters and data scraping (in my case: 3 step clicking-filtering)
4-Starting data refreshment from server(e.g. connecting IE to internet)
5-Loop the whole stages
*** Server automatically refreshes data in every click on the filters***
*** Disconnecting the internet is just an idea to prevent the server from refreshment in order to scrap all data at the specific time***
*** Clicking on one filter takes 5 second that delays data scraping time frame***
I try this sequence manually(by turning off/on the laptop WiFi) and it works. But I need a code to do it automatically.

Sample code(use break point in click lines to see procedure):

```
 Sub Macro1()
```

'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim IE As Object
Dim x As Integer
Set IE = Nothing
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
      .Visible = True
      .navigate ("https://www.dailyfx.com/eur-usd")
    Do While IE.Busy = True: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    While IE.readystate = "complete": DoEvents: Wend
    End With

```
'loop
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("TopIcon MwIcon MwQuery")(0).Click
IE.document.getElementById("FilterIndex").getElementsByTagName("div").Item(0).Click
x = 1
'data scraping LVL1 with first cache object
IE.document.getElementById("FilterIndex").getElementsByTagName("div").Item(0).Click
'data scraping LVL2 with second cache object
x = 2
IE.document.getElementById("FilterIndex").getElementsByTagName("div").Item(0).Click
'data scraping LVL3 with third cache object
x = 3
'loop
IE.Quit
```

'
End Sub

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is your problem. What do you mean by "disconnect the internet"? Can this not be acheived simply by caching the page's XML/HTML into a collection of string before loading the page again?

Comment: It is possible in first click on first filter, but after clicking on next filter data will be refreshed by server. Process contains caching data is in 3 steps with 3 filters clicking. Therefore caching data will be refreshed by every click on every filter.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand, and I can't read the website you're attempting to scrape so it is not very possible for me to understand the nature of your problem. You are clicking a filter but you expect the page contents to NOT change?

Comment: No. Content changes in every clicking on filter(its the nature of webpage). I must click triple times on three separate filters, first click caches data correctly, after second clicking on the second filter webpage content changes. I need all "3 step data" altogether at the same moment. But scraping data in 3steps needs 3 clicking on 3 filters, consequently needs 3 caching. This is the main problem: I need to stop refreshing data (by server) when I change my filters.

Comment: OK, so you want to apply all three filter at same time, so only cache the data once?  BTW: you should edit your question to clarify this as you've done in comments. Unfortuantely, since I cannot read the language of that website, I can't be of much assistance to you, but hopefully someone else may help.

Comment: Data is changing based on the time, and I need all data in a specific time frame(e.g. 10:00:00). By clicking on my filters data updates to next time frame by the server(e.g. second click turns data to 10:00:05 time frame, third click turns data to 10:00:10 time frame).

Comment: yeah man I'm sorry I can't help you, and the proper way to add detail is to *revise* your original post, not to bury it deep within the comments where nobody will ever read it.

Comment: Thanks for your hints.